# mathutils.Quaternion won't do inverse()

Tags: python, blender

I currently have this code which doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
ob = bpy.context.object
ob.rotation_mode = 'QUATERNION'
aux_actual = mathutils.Quaternion(ob.rotation_quaternion)
print (aux_actual)
aux_actual_2 = aux_actual.inverse()
```

Print shows: < Quaternion < w=0.9895, x=0.3434, y=0.0000, z=0.7645  >>

I get the following error message: AttibuteError: Quaternion object has no attribute inverse.

[Mathutils API](https://www.blender.org/api/249PythonDoc/Mathutils.Quaternion-class.html)

Comment: What version are you on? The [current docs](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_2/mathutils.html#mathutils.Quaternion) list `invert` and `inverted` methods, but no `inverse`.

Comment: Using invert() seems to have solved the problem thx :). I was using the API I linked because it was the first result in google.

Comment: Yes the 2.49 docs are getting old. Recently [a new url was setup](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/) that always redirects to the latest api version.

Answer (score 0):

Answer

```
ob = bpy.context.object
ob.rotation_mode = 'QUATERNION'
aux_actual = mathutils.Quaternion(ob.rotation_quaternion)
print (aux_actual)
aux_actual_2 = aux_actual.invert()
```